# sync oddity with wahoo to google fit

Tags: bike-computer

Why does Google Fit show such ridiculously different data from my Wahoo Bolt?

| bryton | wahoo | google |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [image: screenshot of Bryton] | [image: screenshot of Bolt] | [image: screenshot of Google Fit] |

Most values look reasonable but trip distance and average speed are extremely implausible. (Bedford is rather more than a mile away from Oxford...)

The Google Fit data is imported from Wahoo, so I would expect the Google display to show identical data to the Wahoo display.

### Background

I bought a second-generation Wahoo Bolt last week. I'm still learning about its functionality. First time I've navigated by GPS turn-by-turn.

My normal bike-computer is a simple Bryton Rider 410 (used mainly for speed and odometer) which is paired with an ant+ wheel speed sensor and a bluetooth HRM. I tried pairing them with the Wahoo without first unpairing from the Bryton. This seemed to work. However, when both computers were active only the Bryton saw them, so I deleted them from the Bolt (before the ride).

The Bolt app is configured to upload to Google Fit. I am not using Google Fit directly to measure anything.

Comment: Google does the same with data synced from Garmin I gave up using Google Fit for this reason. Plenty of info from a Google search has loads of users saying the same. It’s really not up to the standards of Wahoo or Garmin in terms of GPS accuracy and unfortunately it uses a basic distance / time taken to work out speed

Comment: @DanK Some links please? My googlefu is weak - I didn't find anything before posting here.

Comment: I have also had problems with the synchronization of Wahoo data to Google Fit, including rides that never show up or show up weeks later. I sent feedback on it to Google but haven't complained to Wahoo. Maybe if we both complain to both companies, and a few other people as well, we'll get them to fix it.

Comment: A man with a watch knows what time it is. A man with two watches is never sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer seem to be that Google Fit is just very slow at processing. Not sure precisely when it updated but it now shows slightly more realistic-looking data (I think I trust the odometer mounted on my wheel more than distances calculated from GPS) although it has lost the speed graph:

[image: updated google fit data]

Comment: Can you guess how long it took to come right?  Surely not five months ?

Comment: I think it is common for these sites to do some extra processing after the initial upload.  For example if you do a ride on a mountain bike strava initially gives you a very low average power estimate before updating a short time later.  Regardless, thanks for coming back to give an update

Comment: @Criggie Sorry, haven't needed the wahoo since that ride and I only just thought to re-check. It must have taken at least a few days, given that the original post was already several days after the ride.